# Use "android update" on cmd line to create a new project from existing code

Tags: android, templates, cmd

In the documentation here

https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

it says that

`'android update'`

can be used to create a new project from existing code. The example however does not state how to do exactly that.
Given an existing project folder (basically containing a template android project), how do I create a new project with its own folder from cmd line?

Answer (score 0):

Lennert, really i think 'android update' poor. I wanted copy an existing project, but renaming  the package name, but i couldn't be able to do that, then I did that using script ant.

```
<project name="betorcs" basedir="." >

    <property environment="env" />

    <!-- project directories -->
    <property name="project.dir" value="${basedir}/.." />
    <property name="project.src" value="${project.dir}/src/main/java" />
    <property name="project.res" value="${project.dir}/res" />


    <!-- load configuration file -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="${checklist.file}" />

    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" classpath="libs/xmltask.jar"/>


    <!-- altera o nome do packageName -->
    <target name="-change-package">
        <echo> Name the application package name on manifest.</echo>
        <xmltask encoding="UTF-8" source="${project.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml" dest="${project.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml">
            <copy path="/manifest/@package" property="packageName" />
            <replace path="/manifest/@package" withText="${project.package}" />
        </xmltask>

        <echo> Refactory reference from '${packageName}' to '${project.package}'</echo>
        <replace dir="${project.src}" value="${project.package}.R">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
            <replacefilter
                        token="${packageName}.R"
                        value="${project.package}.R" />
        </replace>

        <replace dir="${project.src}" value="${project.package}.BuildConfig">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
            <replacefilter
            token="${packageName}.BuildConfig"
            value="${project.package}.BuildConfig" />
        </replace>

        <echo> Rename resources from '${packageName}' to '${project.package}'</echo>
        <replace dir="${project.res}" value="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/${project.package}">
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
            <replacefilter
                        token="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/${packageName}"
                        value="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/${project.package}" />
        </replace>
    </target>




</project>
```

```
    Action "update project":
      Updates an Android project (must already have an AndroidManifest.xml).
    Options:
      -l --library    : Directory of an Android library to add, relative to this
                        project's directory.
      -p --path       : The project's directory. [required]
      -n --name       : Project name.
      -t --target     : Target ID to set for the project.
      -s --subprojects: Also updates any projects in sub-folders, such as test
                        projects.

    Action "create project":
      Creates a new Android project.
    Options:
      -n --name    : Project name.
      -t --target  : Target ID of the new project. [required]
      -p --path    : The new project's directory. [required]
      -k --package : Android package name for the application. [required]
      -a --activity: Name of the default Activity that is created. [required]
```